# Dealing with a predictor variable with multiple levels

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data

I am learning multiple regression and attempting to build a multiple regression model using Excel based on how certain variables affect the market penetration of a company in different areas. I have five predictor variables, some are percentages, some are continuous variables, however one predictor variable is "social class" which is split into three levels. Each level is a percentage of the overall population in the area.

Social class is split into "lower", "middle" and "upper", so for one area it could be 20, 30, 50 respectively etc.

How do I deal with this variable when building a multiple regression model?

Comment: Why not have three variables `social.lower`, `social.middle` and `social.upper`? One of these will be redundant, so remove one.